# Extract an item from a JSON response

Tags: python, json

I'm new to Python and JSON.

I'm getting the following response from [Google Maps API](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=11554):

```
{
    "status": "OK", 
    "results": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location_type": "APPROXIMATE", 
                "bounds": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 40.73804080000001, 
                        "lng": -73.5261501
                    }, 
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 40.6944609, 
                        "lng": -73.5836571
                    }
                }, 
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 40.73804080000001, 
                        "lng": -73.5261501
                    }, 
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 40.6944609, 
                        "lng": -73.5836571
                    }
                }, 
                "location": {
                    "lat": 40.7179622, 
                    "lng": -73.5535234
                }
            }, 
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "long_name": "11554", 
                    "types": [
                        "postal_code"
                    ], 
                    "short_name": "11554"
                }, 
                {
                    "long_name": "East Meadow", 
                    "types": [
                        "locality", 
                        "political"
                    ], 
                    "short_name": "East Meadow"
                }, 
                {
                    "long_name": "Hempstead", 
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_3", 
                        "political"
                    ], 
                    "short_name": "Hempstead"
                }, 
                {
                    "long_name": "Nassau County", 
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_2", 
                        "political"
                    ], 
                    "short_name": "Nassau County"
                }, 
                {
                    "long_name": "New York", 
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_1", 
                        "political"
                    ], 
                    "short_name": "NY"
                }, 
                {
                    "long_name": "United States", 
                    "types": [
                        "country", 
                        "political"
                    ], 
                    "short_name": "US"
                }
            ], 
            "place_id": "ChIJr-XSE-J9wokRJzSAdre-1i4", 
            "formatted_address": "East Meadow, NY 11554, USA", 
            "types": [
                "postal_code"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I have parsed out

```
lat 40.7179622 lng -73.5535234 LocType APPROXIMATE
East Meadow, NY 11554, USA
Country: [{u'long_name': u'United States', u'types': [u'country', u'political'], u'short_name': u'US'}]
```

I'm trying to extract the two-letter country code ("US") from here:

```
    Country: [{u'long_name': u'United States', u'types': [u'country', u'political'], u'short_name': u'US'}]
```

This is the code I have:

```
import urllib
import json

serviceurl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'

while True:
    address = raw_input('Enter location: ')
    if len(address) < 1 : break

    url = serviceurl + urllib.urlencode({'sensor':'false', 'address': address})
    print 'Retrieving', url
    uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read()
    #print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'

    try: js = json.loads(str(data))
    except: js = None
    if 'status' not in js or js['status'] != 'OK':
        print '==== Failure To Retrieve ===='
        print data
        continue

    print json.dumps(js, indent=4)

    lat = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
    lng = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
    locType = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location_type"]
    print 'lat',lat,'lng',lng,'LocType', locType
    location = js['results'][0]['formatted_address']
    print location
    address_components=js["results"][0]["address_components"]
    countryFull=address_components[5:6]
    country=countryFull


    print 'Country:', country
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have `print 'Country:', country`,

where `country= [{u'long_name': u'United States', u'types': [u'country', u'political'], u'short_name': u'US'}]`, so that is a list of one element.

`country[0]['short_name]'` should give you `'US'`

If you don't want `country` to be a list, don't slice the `address_components` at `countryFull=address_components[5:6]`. Only get the single JSON object at the necessary position.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it!